# Regular expression java how to addition 2 value?

Tags: java, regex

how can I parse and addition two value?
Im usin this pattern:

```
String s = "6 + 7 =";
```

Included spacing, I need to get "13"

It is possible with regex, or there are an other way to do this easely?

Thanks in advance for ur help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to use regex you can do it this way:

```
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("(\\d+)\\s*\\+\\s*(\\d+)\\s*=");
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher("6 + 7 =");
if (matcher.matches()) {
    System.out.println(Integer.valueOf(matcher.group(1)) + Integer.valueOf(matcher.group(2)));
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Does it have to be regex? If not you can use JavaScript engine (since Java 1.6) to do calculations from String, like:

```
ScriptEngineManager factory = new ScriptEngineManager();
// create a JavaScript engine
ScriptEngine engine = factory.getEngineByName("JavaScript");

Double d=(Double)engine.eval("1 + 2 * 3");
System.out.println(d);
```